# Error on finding controller from Laravel API Router

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I created a fresh Laravel framework.

I created a controller named PostsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::get();

        return response()->success(compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

Then I created a route in the file `api.php`:

```
Route::get('posts', 'PostsController@index');
```

I ran the command

```
$ php artisan serve`
```

and I tested the URL

```
localhost:8000/api/posts
```

This error occurs:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::success does not exist.

file: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php
line: 100

throw new BadMethodCallException("Method {$class}::{$method} does not exist.");
```

I can't understand why this happened. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `success` method on the `ResponseFactory`. You can find the available methods [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.html).

Comment: thanks a lot. I have followed a wrong document. I replaced success() with json() and it works ..

Comment: Thanks @RohamRafii, the link to the documentation is broken, this is the same issue I had, json() solved it!

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.php   link for laravel 8.x

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a macro function that is not registerd to the responseFactory.To use success method,Create your custom responseServiceProvider and write this inside boot()

```
Response::macro('success',function($data){
            return Response::json([
                'data'=>$data,
            ]) ;
        });
```

And then register your ResponseServiceProvider  to app.php by adding  your  Class name to the array called providers. This is how you add to the array

```
App\Providers\ResponseMacroServiceProvider::class
```

Answer (score 0):

For me i got this error because , i not add "use HttpResponse;" on my controller class;
So just add "use HttpResponse;" on your controller class after your class declaration.